# selenium (Firefox in background), sendkeys works but does not focus

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to run selenium for Firefox as a background process.
I have to send text to an input box and then send Tab key to select a dynamically visible drop-down.

Selenium is able to enter the text correctly but it is not able to send the tab key in the desired manner, i.e. when I try to send tab after text, the tab key erases the text (when running the firefox browser in background).

Moreover, when I send text followed by tab with Firefox in foreground, everything runs fine. Text is typed in, the input box has the cursor focus and when followed by a tab key, correct option from the drop-down is chosen.

Can anyone please help me to make the process run successfully in background.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet that reproduces your problem? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with click in input box before sendkeys. So click -> sendkeys -> tab